# Post-Brexit: Am I supposed to register and charge UK VAT?

Tags: uk, remote, eu, vat

Something that has been unclear for me post-brexit. I am a sole proprietor located in the Netherlands and am providing a remote service (B2B) to a UK company. In 2020 during the brexit transition, I would invoice with a VAT Reverse Charge.

Now, I'm not sure what to invoice with. My local government can't help me more, other than telling me I don't charge Dutch VAT and can't reverse charge anymore --> VAT out of EU scope. They don't know the full implications either. Articles I've read by the Chamber of commerce have information that varies from, VAT of Scope, VAT Reverse Charge and UK VAT applies.

When I made a call to the HMRC explaining my situation, I got told that I **should** register for a **UK VAT Number and charge UK VAT**. Referring to these articles:

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/vat-notice-7001-should-i-be-registered-for-vat/vat-notice-7001-should-i-be-registered-for-vat

(2.3 taxable supplies)

*"you’re an NETP (see section 9), and you make any taxable supplies in the UK, regardless of their value and including supplies of digital services --> you must register for VAT"*

(8.1 NETP – definition)

*"A non-established taxable person (NETP) is any person who is not normally resident in the UK, does not have a UK establishment and, in the case of a company, is not incorporated in the UK"*

Basically I've heard a lot of contradicting information and I don't know which is more accurate. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It looks as though the HMRC guidance is fairly clear in that you're a non-established person selling taxable supplies in the UK.

Personally, I'd do as they suggest unless you have a good reason not to do so.